# Concatenate Path.Getfilename(filename) Upload Files to SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, concatenation, filestream

I am trying to write a Program that Transfers Files to SharePoint, I am using Filestream since the servers this will pull from are File Servers. I am having trouble concatenating `Path.Getfilename(filename)` and the literal string inside `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaverBinaryDirect(context,"",fs,true);` I am more of an admin than a programmer. Any help would be great.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       ClientContext context = new    ClientContext("https://company.sharepoint.com");
       {
          SecureString password = new SecureString();
          foreach (char c in "Password")
             password.AppendChar(c);
          context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("UserEmail", password);
          context.ExecuteQuery();
          Console.WriteLine("File Transfer is Complete");
       }

       string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\directorypath");
       foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(fileName);
           Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(fileName));
           using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
           {
                Path.Combine(fileName,Path.GetFileName(fileName.Replace("/sites/Name ofSite/documentlibrary/", "")));
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(context, "", fs, true);  
           }


         }
     }
}
```

Comment: [String.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) returns a new `string` and doesn't change the `string` it's used on. Looks like you want to replace (remove) path information from `filename`, but you put it into [Path.GetFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx), which already does that for you, so just use `Path.GetFileName(filename)`. The question is, why are you trying to combine the (whole) `filename` with just the FileName part of `filename`? The result would look something like `"c:\path\subpath\file.ext\file.ext"`.

Comment: Could you give an (anonymised) example of a full path-and-filename and the result you want to get to?

Comment: My attempt is pull mulitple files from one server into Sharepoint,

Comment: @"C:\\Users\Marco.Polo\Desktop\filename

Comment: So that is the "source" file? `@"C:\Users\Marco.Polo\Desktop\filename"`? Great. And what would the desired "destination" file look like? -- oh, wait, would it just be `"/sites/Name ofSite/documentlibrary/filename"`?

Comment: /sites/Name ofSite/documentlibrary/filename" yes

Comment: If so, try: `string destination = "/sites/Name ofSite/documentlibrary/" + Path.GetFileName(filename);` --- (or `string destination = "/sites/Name ofSite/documentlibrary/" + Path.GetFileName(filename);`)

Comment: How would that look in the code?

Answer (score 0):

[`File.SaveBinaryDirect Method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee538285(v=office.14)) expects for `serverRelativeUrl` parameter *a string that represents the server-relative URL of the file*,for example:

```
/site/web/documents/file.zip
```

To construct file *server relative url* you could combine list/library server relative url and file name:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
{
     var fileUrl =  "/site/web/documents/" + Path.GetFileName(fileName);
     Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(ctx, fileUrl, fs, true);
}
```

**Modified example**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //source settings (local file system)
        var sourcePath = @"C:\Users\jdoe\Documents";

        //target settings (SharePoint Online)
        var webUrl = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/";
        var username = "jdoe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com";
        var password = "password";
        var targetListTitle = "Documents";

        var fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);  //retrieve source files

        using (var ctx = GetContext(webUrl, username, password))
        {

            //prepare target list
            var targetList = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(targetListTitle);
            ctx.Load(targetList, l => l.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();


            foreach (var fileName in fileNames)
            {
                using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    var fileUrl = targetList.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + Path.GetFileName(fileName);
                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(ctx, fileUrl, fs, true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

where

```
    private static ClientContext GetContext(string url,string username, string password)
    {
        var ctx = new ClientContext(url);
        var securePassword = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in password) securePassword.AppendChar(c);
        ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securePassword);
        return ctx;
    }
```